# Is the auto generated serialVersionUID always the same for all instances of the same class?

Tags: java, serialization

The reason I ask this is because I am currently getting this error

> java.io.InvalidClassException: com.my.package.TestObject; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8401131515464509133, local class serialVersionUID = 581907934314849590

I get this because I am reading an old version of an object from a Redis cache but I have changed the object to have a new field - the old version of the class did not originally have a serialVersionUID so it's using this auto-generated one.

e.g old version

```
public static class TestObject implements Serializable {
        String id;
        String name;
    }
```

new version

```
public static class TestObject implements Serializable {
        String id;
        String name;
        String newField;
    }
```

**Q** - So my question is if I add `private static final long serialVersionUID = 8401131515464509133L` to the class will it be a problem for other instances of the object?

**EDIT**: the main question I am asking is does the value that was computed for the auto-generated serialVersionUuid each time a class is compiled? 
or
can I rely on it been the same every compile? (when no new fields are added)?

Comment: What do you mean by 'problem for other instances'?

Comment: I mean other older versions of the object instances of TestObject that are in the Redis Cache that will be deserialized

Comment: This case above did not originally have the serialVersionUUID

Comment: It's the same unless you changed something in the class that would change it, which is almost anything, and you did. This is all documented.

Comment: OK thanks, so I can rely on the value 8401131515464509133 to be the same for all objects in my external Cache, add that serial uuid into my new class and thus a safe workaround

Answer (score -1):

Yes, for the same JRE you see the same default serialVersionUID for a class.

No, for different different versions of JRE.

In your case you can probably define explicit serialVersionUID that should help, but from your question that's not obvious, if all objects have been serialized by the same JRE. If not there is still a risk it won't help in all cases as explained below.

Once you change serialVersionUID of a class you can no longer deserialize older objects event though the rest of the class remain unchanged. Using default serialVersionUID is danger as well, because it gets calculated by JVM and there is no guarantee on consistency when you for example upgrade JRE version.

If you experience the issue with object serialization, you can try 
http://marjavamitjava.com/make-java-runtime-ignore-serialversionuids-deserializing/

But I'd prefer to use a different serializer than Java native binaries.

Comment: My problem here is I can't deserialize an older version of an object unless I explicitly add the serial version uuid from the exception above

Comment: @M_K So do that.

Comment: @M_K default serialVersionUID is calculated in runtime, not in the compilation time. Thus you see a 'magic' number. You should always declared explicit serialVersionUID to prevent that issue. But you still cannot change any property even though serialVersionUID is the same.

Comment: you can hard code all of these to something like 1L and then change them as needed when an object is not backwards compatible with an earlier cached value. If an class has newly added optional attributes its usually still serializable. Its just when attributes that change their type or are removed that you normally have to change the serialVersionUID to trigger the flushing / ignoring of incompatible types